# How to use third party libraries with Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I've downloaded **Algebird** and I want to try out few things in the **Scala interpreter** using this library. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Normally, there is also a `:cp` command from the REPL prompt, but that has been broken; it may return in 2.11.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Of course, you can use scala -cp whatever and manually manage your dependencies. But that gets quite tedious, especially if you have multiple dependencies.

A more flexible approach is to use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) to manage your dependencies. Search for the library you want to use on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org). Algebird for example is available by simply [searching for algebird](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Calgebird). Then create a build.sbt referring to that library, enter the directory and enter **sbt console**. It will download all your dependencies and start a scala console session with all dependencies automatically on the classpath.

Changing things like the scala version or the library version is just a simple change in the build.sbt. To play around you don't need any scala code in your directory. An empty directory with just the build.sbt will do just fine.

Here is a *build.sbt* for using algebird:

```
name := "Scala Playground"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "algebird-core" % "0.2.0"
```

Edit: often when you want to play around with a library, the first thing you have to do is to import the namespace(s) of the library. This can also be automated in the build.sbt by adding the following line:

```
initialCommands in console += "import com.twitter.algebird._"
```

Comment: SBT can take care of a lot of other things too, e.g. downloading of other dependencies the library may have, picking the right version depending on your scalaVersion value, and it can even switch "on the fly" between scala versions by typing e.g. at the sbt prompt `set scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"`.  I highly recommend using SBT to experiment with new libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. As a new person to Scala (coming from ruby and it's marvelous gem system), this has been a big frustration for me. The clarity you've offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would I use this build.sbt to launch a sbt REPL that loads the algebird library?

Comment: Create a directory containing just the build.sbt. Then launch `sbt console` from that directory.

Comment: I highly recommend you to check other sbt (console) features as well, for example, being able to continuously compile and test with triggered executions is highly useful. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html

Answer (score 18):

Running `sbt console` will not import libraries declared with a test scope. To use those libraries in the REPL, start the console with

```
sbt test:consoleQuick
```

You should be aware, however, that starting the console this way skips compiling your test sources.

Source: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Scala.html

Comment: @Zoltan : How does sbt know what is in test scope and what is not? My sbt contains just `libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0" % "test")`. And there is no 'test scoping' here.

Comment: @Ashwin the `% "test"` at the end of that line is exactly what tells SBT that this dependency is only for tests. If you leave it out, it will become a compile dependency.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the scala's `-cp` switch to keep jars on the classpath. There are other switches available too, for example,  `-deprecation` and `-unchecked` for turning on various warnings. Many more to be found with `scala -X...` and `scala -Y...`. You can find out more information about these switches with `scala -help`

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer using [Ammonite](https://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL) (as opposed to the Scala REPL) - but it is such a great tool that it is worth mentioning.

1. You can install it with a one liner such as:

```sh
sudo sh -c '(echo "#!/usr/bin/env sh" && curl -L https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/download/2.1.2/2.13-2.1.2) > /usr/local/bin/amm && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/amm' && amm
```

or using brew on macOS:

```
brew install ammonite-repl
```

For scala 2.10, you need to use an oder version 1.0.3:

```sh
sudo sh -c '(echo "#!/usr/bin/env sh" && curl -L https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/download/1.0.3/2.10-1.0.3) > /usr/local/bin/amm && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/amm' && amm
```

2. Run Ammonite in your terminal:

```
amm
// Displays
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 2.1.0 (Scala 2.12.11 Java 1.8.0_242)
```

3. Use in ivy import to import your 3rd part library:

```
import $ivy.`com.twitter::algebird-core:0.2.0`
```

Then you can use your library within the Ammonite-REPL:

```
import com.twitter.algebird._
import com.twitter.algebird.Operators._
Map(1 -> Max(2)) + Map(1 -> Max(3)) + Map(2 -> Max(4))
...
```