# What is the difference of running `scala` and `sbt console`?

Tags: scala, sbt

What is the difference of running the scala shell in these different ways?

Comment: Useful `sbt console` reference: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

SBT is tied to a specific project defined by a `build.sbt` file in a way that `$ sbt console` will load up the same REPL environment as `$ scala` but with the addition of all of the project code and dependencies defined in the build available for import. Also, it will use the version of Scala defined by `build.sbt`.

For example:

```
$ scala
scala> import scalaz._
<console>:7: error: not found: value scalaz
       import scalaz._
```

but with this `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.0"
```

the import succeeds:

```
$ sbt console
...
scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._
```

The command loads Scala 2.11.4 instead of the system wide Scala (or any version of it on `PATH`).

Furthermore, invoking `sbt console` after adding new items in the build’s `libraryDependencies` will fetch them.

Comment: And if you don't want to force compilation of the current project’s sources, try `sbt consoleQuick` (see https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html)

Answer (score 8):

If you call scala, you will get whatever scala version is installed on the path of your operating system.

If you call sbt console, you get the scala version configured in the sbt build (build.sbt) *with all libraries that are used in the build already on the classpath*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812399/how-to-use-third-party-libraries-with-scala-repl/18812934#18812934) for details.