# -bash: scala: command not found

Tags: macos, scala, installation

I'm trying to install scala on my mac (Maverick).
I downloaded and unarchived it.
I then put myself from where it was unarchived and inside the /bin folder in the terminal.
But when I run "scala" or "scalac" I get :

`-bash: scala: command not found`

Why?

Comment: have you tried `./scala` instead of `scala`

Comment: Also have you verified that the downloaded archive was for mac and not for win or linux.

Comment: `sbt console` may be a useful alternative; see [what-is-the-difference-of-running-scala-and-sbt-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192398/what-is-the-difference-of-running-scala-and-sbt-console)

Answer (score 12):

I always suggest that mac users install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and use homebrew as their primary package installer to install software.

Installing scala is as simple as

```
brew install scala
```

Homebrew will also install/fix java dependencies for you and handle path issues (I believe)

Comment: Also, for anyone using homebrew to fix scala issues, if you're also getting a "bash command not found" error for the `sbt` command after running `brew install scala`, you can try running `brew upgrade sbt` afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I get the same issue and quickly I found everything is fine, if you write the correct path into your .bash_profile.

The only thing you need is to **close current terminal and open a new one**, on which Scala would work.

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

do you have Java installed and available on your PATH http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Java/README.html the same author also provides good Scala / SBT setup info http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Java/README.html