# How to put org.apache in Scala import path?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classpath

I have spark 1.6.0 installed and would like to import it in Scala 2.11. I can use spark-shell, which has org.apache in its path. How do I put it in my system installation of scala's path?

Comment: Please don't use [tag:apache] for questions not related to Apache HTTP Server :) It could be also useful if you explain what you mean by _installed_. By default Spark binaries in < 2.0 are built with Scala 2.10.

Comment: Sorry about that.
'Installed' is a good question. It means there is a precompiled binary in a folder.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by keeping org.apache in scala.? Do you want to execute spark-shell or you want to import any spark package in spark-shell.?

Comment: I want to import spark libraries in the regular scala shell. For example:
import org.apache.spark

Comment: this may be duplicate of this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812399/how-to-use-third-party-libraries-with-scala-repl
You would need to get the desired libraries from maven and then use it with above instructions of using cp option
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11