# Why can't scala find what sbt can?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

With sbt everything is fine:

```
» sbt console
[info] Loading project definition from /repos/myrepo/project
[info] Set current project to bpavscan (in build file:/repos/myrepo/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala>
```

But if I do it with the scala tool:

```
» scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import play.api.libs.json._
<console>:7: error: not found: value play
       import play.api.libs.json._
              ^

scala>
```

I need to run a simple script, which I usually do with:

```
scala myscript.scala
```

But since now my script has a play dependency, I can not run it with scala anymore, since scala does not find play.

I need to either:

1. Be able to load the play framework with the simple scala tool
2. Be able to run a simple script with `sbt`: `sbt run` runs my project, which I do not want. I want to run a simple script (to try out some simple things)

Comment: Because the Scala REPL has no clue as to what your dependencies are, while SBT is literally in charge of managing all your project dependencies.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov how can I run a simple script making use of the installed dependencies? Is there a `sbt runscript <myscript.scala>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812399/how-to-use-third-party-libraries-with-scala-repl

Answer (score 2):

`sbt console` with load the same `console/REPL` as of `scala` but with additional loaded dependencies defined in `build.sbt`. So before loading the console, all the dependent libraries are added. And this is reason you could `import play` libraries while using `sbt console`.

On the other hand `scala` starts the `console` with the libraries inside `scala-package` of the system. Thus needs additional `jars` being included inside the package for `importing`. For the above case if play library jar was included in `scala` directory then `import play.api.libs.json._` should have worked for `scala console` too.