# NullPointerException on XML.loadFile()

Tags: scala, scala-xml, scala-2.12, scala-2.13

I am trying to load an xml file using `scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar` but it gives me `NullPointerEexception` while loading

Following is my line of code to load xml

```
import scala.xml.XML
val xml = XML.loadFile("sample.xml")
```

I have decompiled this jar and is method is present in that jar but for some reasons it is unable to find it in code.

I have `Scala 2.13.1` on my system but for this project I am using  `scala 2.12.1` and it is mentioned in mu `built.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
```

I have following dependency in my `built.sbt` for this xml package

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
```

If I copy and paste the same code to `Scala` interactive shell( `scala 2.13.1`)  I get following error

```
import scala.xml.XML
                ^
   error: object xml is not a member of package scala
   did you mean Nil?
```

Can anyone please identify what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more info to help you. Have you tried adding this to build.sbt?

Comment: @IvaKam thanks for replying me, I have the library dependency for this xml package with which I am facing this issue . I have added that in my question, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are loading up the Scala REPL, but as mentioned in ["How to use third party libraries with Scala REPL?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812934/12066468), you should be launching the the REPL from SBT with `sbt console`. Your `.sbt` files will also need to be in scope.

The Scala REPL independently does not deal with `.sbt` files. They are 2 different tools.

Alternatively you could also install [Ammonite-REPL](https://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL) which supports [Magic Imports](https://ammonite.io/#MagicImports). You will be able to import Maven dependencies with `import $ivy`.

Scala 2.12 comes with `scala-xml` and you can remove that dependency as long as you run REPL with `sbt console` and not your native Scala REPL which is already @ Scala 2.13. Otherwise you can also switch to Scala 2.13 for your SBT project.